# PHP cURL - Why does script die after 36th request to a remote URL?

Tags: php, curl, timeout, remote-server, limits

I am trying to scrape a website's pages to get certain text content. 
New pages are always being added, so I want to be able to just increment through each page (using a fixed format URL) until I get a 404.

**Pages are in this format:**

http://thesite.com/page-1.html

http://thesite.com/page-2.html

http://thesite.com/page-3.html

...etc....

Everything runs smoothly until it hits the 36th page, then just dies (doesn't even hit the 404 test case). I know that there are about 100 pages that exist in this example, and I can manually view them all without a problem. Also, there is no error on the 36th page.

*Test Case - I tried looping through http://google.com 50 times and had no problem with the cURL recursion. Just seems to be the website I actually want to cURL, or something with my server.*

It seems to be some sort of limit either on the remote server, or my server, as I can run this page over and over again with no delay and I always get 36 pages read before it dies.

**Can remote servers set a limit to cURL requests? Is there any other timeouts I need to increment? Is it a possible server memory issue?**

**Recursive Scraping Function: ** *(The $curl object is created in the first call to the method, then just passed by reference. I read this was better than creating and closing large amounts of cURL objects)*

```
function scrapeSite(&$curl,$preURL,$postURL,$parameters,$currentPage){
        //Format URL
        $formattedURL = $preURL.$currentPage.$postURL;
        echo "Formatted URL: ".$formattedURL."<br>";
        echo "Count: ".$currentPage."<br>";
        //Create CURL Object
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $formattedURL);

        //Set PHP Timeout
        set_time_limit(0);// to infinity for example
        //Check for 404
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($httpCode == 404 || $currentPage == 50) {
            curl_close($curl);
            return 'PAGE NOT FOUND<br>';
        }
        //Set other CURL Options
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
        $content = curl_exec($curl);
        $html = str_get_html($content);
        echo "Parameter Check: ".is_array($html->find($parameters))."<br>";
        if(is_array($html->find($parameters))>0){
            foreach($html->find($parameters) as $element) {
                echo "Text: ".$element->plaintext."<br>";
            }
            return scrapeSite($curl,$preURL,$postURL,$parameters,$currentPage+1);
        }else{
            echo "No Elements Found";
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe firewall blocking?

Comment: Would firewall blocking not block requests if I reload the page? I can reload the page back to back as many times as I want, and the script always runs, just stops at 36th page.

Comment: Does it connect 36 times  simultaneously?  Or 1 by 1? Finish 1 page then continue to the next?

Comment: @CreativeMind 1 page after another. Loops through current page to find specified elements, then once finished calls recursive function to move on to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe its just memory limit problem try this(at the top of script).

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

And also you said "... or something with my server" ,so if you can, just read your logs...

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Shouldn't use unlimited memory though, so I set it to 1GB: ini_set('memory_limit', '1000000000');